# Which combination of 3 hyperparameters to combat overfitting of a convolutional neural network?

Tags: overfitting, hyperparameter-tuning, convolutional-neural-network, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I have a small dataset with which I want to train a CNN by using Data Augmentation. Since the CNN is overfitting due to the small data set, I would like to optimize some hyperparameters.
However, since I would like to use GridSearchCV from Scikit-Learn for this and I would therefore like to optimize only 3 hyperparameters due to reducing computational time. Here the question arises which combination of hyperparameters should I use for grid search?

My current approach would be to optimize the learning rate, the dropout layer rate and the number of epochs.

I choose the learning rate because the book "Deep Learning" by Goodfellow recommends to always optimize the learning rate. But I'm not sure if my combination of hyperparameters for tuning is really good.

What combination would you recommend?
Many thank for every hint

My previous architectur is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(512))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

As optimizer I use Adam.

Comment: and which library are you planning to use for the model? is Keras an option?

Comment: @serali yes, I use keras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking specifically about overfitting, I would only keep dropout rate from your list of three. Other two can be any chosen from: number of filters in the convolutional layers, number of convolutions, number of dense layers (if any), number of neurons in dense layers.

Learning rate should be optimized but not for the purpose of combatting overfitting, at least the way I understand it. Using Keras, you can start with some learning rate - not necessarily very fine tuned, and slowly reduce it over time once the training reaches a plateau using **Learning Rate Scheduler** in [Callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/). Also, there are ways to find an optimal learning rate such as [learning rate finder](https://docs.fast.ai/callbacks.lr_finder.html#callbacks.lr_finder), so it would probably be a misuse of resources to optimize for learning rate using grid search (I never used them though!).

You can also use the **Model Checkpoint** present in the above Callbacks page to save the model as the validation loss improves only, and ignore the later epochs where overfitting becomes an issue. This way, you won't need to include number of epochs in your search.

Comment: @ serali If I use EarlyStopping to save the search for a optimal number of epochs, this would be at the expense of an additional validation data set, which would only be used for EarlyStopping? The dataset I use is only a subset of a bigger dataset. When I use my previous CNN-architecture for training with the big dataset than I have almost no overfitting. There I would like to keep my previous architectur if possible, hope that makes sense?

Comment: I added my previous architectur to my question above

Comment: I would modify several parts of that architecture, but none directly related to overfitting but rather performance. If you say it performs keep it as it is.

Comment: ok, if I may ask. Which parts of the architecture would you modify?

Comment: Well I would use Batch Norm after ReLU, not before. Also I would remove dropouts after pooling layers and instead use SpatialDropout on convolutional layers directly.

Comment: Sorry to return to your last answer after so many days. Two questions: Why would you set the batch norm after the activation function and why SpatialDropout directly behind the conv layer?

Comment: I remember some discussion here and there saying that despite the ordering presented in the original paper, BN after ReLU works better in practice. And that is also what I found out in my own models by trial and error. As for Spatial Dropout; their purpose are to drop features directly from convolutions, so that is how they should be used, I suppose - but I did not do any experiments on that personally.

Comment: I have also seen these discussions about BN, although here no final decision seems to have been made whether BN before or after ReLU. I only know from this page https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-reduce-overfitting-with-dropout-regularization-in-keras/ that SpatialDropout is used direct after ConvLayer, but without explanation. Many thanks for your explanation